# DBpedia Request company with CEO (or Director)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I made this request in Dbpedia to get a company name with its abstract but I would like to retrieve the current Director /CEO.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        

SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?description 
where{
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name;
  dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description;
  rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en.
  FILTER( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

I tried to perform :

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        

SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?ceo ?description 
where{
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name.
  ?company dbpedia-owl:ceo ?ceo;
  dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description;
  rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en.
  FILTER( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

But I got no result.

Anyone have suggestions about this request ?

Comment: Look at the resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microsoft itself, there is no `dbpedia-owl:ceo` property. The only option is `dbpedia-owl:keyPerson` which in fact doesn't return the latest but all over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the comment of @AKSW I change my request to get the result I need

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?name (GROUP_CONCAT(?ceo_entity; separator=",") as ?ceos) ?description 
where
{
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name.
  ?company dbpedia-owl:keyPerson/foaf:name ?ceo_entity.
  ?company dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description;
  rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en.
  FILTER( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

I explain my request for anyone who need to use and customize it :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name (GROUP_CONCAT(?ceo_entity; separator=",") as ?ceos) ?description
```

I Select the name of the company in a column then I concat the names of CEOs as ceos columns and finally I select the description in the last column.

The first part of my WHERE clause is :

```
?company a dbpedia-owl:Company.
?company foaf:name ?name.
?company dbpedia-owl:keyPerson/foaf:name ?ceo_entity.
?company dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description;
```

I want `?company` is an entity of class Company then I want the property Name in my column `?name`. Moreover I ask the property name of the entity keyPerson in the column ( will be concat to get only one row) `?ceo_entity` and I ask for the abstract ( description of the company) in the column `?description`.

```
rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en.
FILTER( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
```

This part allow me to get only Company with the label "Microsoft" where the description is in English.

The result will be :

```
          name             |       ceos                            |description
"Microsoft Corporation"@en | Bill Gates,John W. Thompson,Satya...  | "Micro..."
```

Comment: keyPerson is not necessarily the CEO of the company. keyPerson can be a C level executive, Board Member, or Founder. How can one further delineate the CEO of the company?